# Online card games: game loop or event based?

Tags: game-loop, turn-based, card-game

The only games I've made have been the game loop variety. I'm just starting to think about building an online poker game where people could meet up in a lobby, etc. Cards seem event based... is the game loop strategy viable here? Or is it just a waste of time to keep running while waiting for someone to make a move?

Comment: How can you check if someone made a move if you don't run something continuously to do just that?

Comment: Using events/messages, as is common in GUI applications.

Comment: Doesn't then, an event listener, have to continuously <listen>?

Comment: Or from another point of view, remain active?

Comment: You've never heard of event listeners and/or the Observer pattern? Long story short, yes something does have to be continuously listening, but that something could just be one organized hub rather than everything in the entire game looping over and over.

Comment: My point is, a loop still exists somewhere.

Comment: Depending on the expected time between messages it doesn't need to be a loop - it could be callback mechanism that runs every x seconds and checks for recent events. For a poker game you would likely need to be responsive, so an ongoing process checking for events would be better than an approach where you check every so often. But for slower game types scheduled checks are acceptable.

Comment: I take "the game loop strategy" to mean something more significant than just some sort of loop somewhere in the program. Although now that I'm saying that, it would be helpful if the question explains better what exactly is meant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly separate your game engine from the rest of the project, such as GUI, net code, etc. The game engine itself should be event-based, let the OS provide the "game loop" in form of its regular event handling. Make all game events that are relevant to the outside accessible through events to which the GUI and all other parts can subscribe. Then you are free to implement your GUI whichever way you want.